# Problem connecting the wireless keyboard and joystick via bluetooth Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:a725 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth 5.1 Radio
```

Keyboard model: AKKO 3098 BT3.0
Manufactured manual:
Press FN+E/R/T   it's OK!
Bluelight flash quickly

Then:

```
[bluetooth]# pair B4:EE:25:F3:CB:B3
Attempting to pair with B4:EE:25:F3:CB:B3
[CHG] Device B4:EE:25:F3:CB:B3 Connected: yes
[agent] PIN code: 667943
[AKKO 3098 BT3.0]
```

Then I, logically, type the given pin-code on the keyboard and nothing happens, if I type the code and press enter nothing happens either and the process aborts by timeout.

```
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout
[CHG] Device B4:EE:25:F3:CB:B3 Connected: no
```

Full manual:

> 1.Switch to Bluetooth mode
> 2.Set the Bluetooth proﬁle To help user recognize individual Bluetooth device, the keyboard is equipped with both Bluetooth 5.0 and 3.0
> frameworks. The device  name under the Bluetooth 5.0 framework is Akko
> 3068BT-1 / Akko 3068BT-2 / Akko 3068BT-3 while the device name under
> Bluetooth 3.0  is AKK0 3068 BT3.0. Once the devices are paired through
> Fn + E/R/T, the system will by default memorize the last connected
> device before  you turn off the Bluetooth mode. ① When the keyboard
> remains unplugged, turn the back switch to ON. Then long press and
> hold Fn + E / R / T to start pairing with  Bluetooth devices. The
> keyboard will enter Bluetooth pairing mode when the blue LEDs under E
> / R / T keys ﬂash quickly.  ② When the Keyboard is plugged into the
> computer through USB interface, it will enter Bluetooth mode
> automatically without having to  push the switch on the back. Users
> can directly long press and hold Fn + E / R / T to enable Bluetooth
> pairing. The keyboard will enter  Bluetooth pairing mode when the blue
> LEDs under E / R / T keys ﬂash quickly.

Need assistant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite trivial, my bluetooth adapter was connected to the computer through an extension cord, and for this reason there was a bad contact, as a result, the keyboard was seen only by bluetooth version 3, which led to pairing problems. I tried re-pairing the adapter and miraculously, everything worked as it should. I removed the adapter and switched it to the slot directly to the computer, and since then there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Keychron keyboard. I solved with a simple `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.